# How to reset a Hive Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am playing around with the Hive Database for Flutter, and when I am trying to save an object, the documentations says about [Adapters](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter) clearly:

> As you can see, each field has a unique number (unique per class). These field numbers are used to identify the fields in the Hive binary format, and should not be changed once your class is in use.

So, after some refactoring, I need to change the classes and some attributes, including his numeration. After doing that obviously the database gives me error (was working perfectly before), and given that all the data from the database is dum data for testing purposes, I would like to Reser and restart a new Database form 0. I did try several things, like `box.clear()` or `Hive.deleteFromDisk()` after opening the boxes, but I am still getting an error about the Adapter attribute type does not match with another in the normal class (referencing the one before refactoring and changing the index).

How can I successfully remove all information and clean the database to start from Zero as a new install??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, what happens to this guys is exactly what happens to me: https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/181  But of course I am talking about a solution when you change the number, to reset the whole database not to go back to the previous number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okkey, I found the answer:

The way to start the app as a new installation in the emulator is to desvnstall the app from the emulator and install it again.

Of course, if new changes to the index number in the Adapter, I would need to recreate these steps:

-Delete the adapters created

-Run `flutter clean`

-Delete the app from the emulator

-Create the new adapters with `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

-Run the app again

Hope is useful for someone in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see I had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

1. First of all, delete the .hive and .lock files generated by hive when you first launch your application in the parent directory of your project.
2. Come back to modify it is what you want in your model and launch the following command:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```